# Design pattern for Service Fabric Actor executing long running processing

Tags: azure-service-fabric

we are designing a new application with Service Fabric and we would like to delegate an Actor the execution of a long running process, but we also want to not block another calls to Actor's methods while it's executing. What is the design pattern (or best practices) to do that ?

Thanks
Antonio

Answer (score 1):

I dont think Actor is what you are looking and also stated in Azure documentation

> Your problem space involves a large number (thousands or more) of small, independent, and isolated units of state and logic.